# How to integrate m3u8 download into Scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, m3u8

I'm trying to download m3u8 files from http://livetv.sx using scrapy.
So far, I've found the code allowing me to get the `.m3u8` file and I would like now to download its content.

I've seen the section titled [Using different HTTP clients](https://github.com/globocom/m3u8#using-different-http-clients), but I don't fully understand how to have both things working together.

So, when I call `m3u8.load('http://videoserver.com/playlist.m3u8', http_client=ScrapyClient())` what should I put in my `ScrapyClient` class ?

Comment: You cannot simply replace `RequestsClient` with `ScrapyClient` and hope things will work. Since they have an API and even a client library, why don’t you just use them? Why would you want to use Scrapy?

Comment: @Gallaecio I had never realized I could use their API instead of scraping their site. THis changes everything!

Comment: @Gallaecio is there any link to the API you entionned? I can't find any reference on their site

Comment: https://github.com/globocom/m3u8

Comment: @Gallaecio Well, my question may be poorly worded, but I'm precisely planning to use that library. But as I don't kknow the precise m3u8 url, I have to rely upon scrapy (or another http client library) to get it from the page ...

Comment: What about using Scrapy to get the URL, and then just using the regular code from that library to download it? The client code will block Scrapy, but if performance is not an issue, I would just do it. Otherwise, you could use deferToThread for m3u8 calls.